Can the physics behind AR glasses be entirely modeled by geometric optics?
If I wanted to get the image of a small LED screen to be reflected onto the lens of a pair of glasses, would an understanding of geometric optics be sufficient to model this scenario?
I ask this question because a few days ago, I looked at some patents of some designs for AR glasses. The designs seemed to be much more complex than just simple magnification, as the design accounted for mitigating ambient light from diluting the reflected image quality.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
